Error while registering for Events
In our CiviCRM instance (CiviCRM 5.74.4 with Drupal), when a customer tries to register for an event, the following error is shown in the end of the process:
Expected one contribution but found 0.
This only happens if SEPA direct debit payment method is chosen, and the email notification is activated in the form.
The data is anyway stored in the system (and looks correct). But the customers are re-doing the registration, which is why a lot of participation fees are booked multiple times via SEPA direct debit.
A similar error occurs when running a PHP script that reads bank reports and creates payments in CiviCRM via the API.
The script throws this error:

CRM_Core_Exception: Expected one Contribution but found 0 in civicrm_api3() (line 138 of .../httpdocs/staging/public/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php).

We found out that in /sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.project60.sepa/CRM/Utils/SepaTokens.php, there is a non-existent variable called $mandate['entity_id']. The $mandate array does not have a key entity_id.
Furthermore, the same file contains also this line:
$firstCollectionDate = $calculator-calculateNextCollectionDate($mandate['entity_id']);

where the function calculateNextCollectionDate in sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.project60.sepa/CRM/Sepa/Logic/NextCollectionDate.php expects the contrib_recur_id as a parameter, but receives the entity_id (read: contribution id) instead.
We fixed this by introducing the contrib_recur_id here, but the error persists.
Edit:
SEPA Direct Debit: Version 1.11.0
CiviSEPA Payment Processor: Version 1.1.0
We also realised that when creating a payment via API Explorer on one Contribution that usually throws this fatal error when the script is run, and then deleting this payment again, then the script can also create a payment on this one Contribution. It seems that creating a payment via API changes the Contribution in a way that solves the problem. Even though in the database and in the API Explorer, we cannot see any notable difference.
Anybody has a hint?

Could you indicate your Versions of CiviCRM, your CMS, the CiviSEPA Extension as well as the CiviSEPA Payment Processors extension?
